# javascript shorthand syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, shorthand, shorthand-if

I was wondering how this could be written in shorthand that the statement would execute

This one isn't working, but I see this kind of syntax lots of times in plugins - variables  mixed with statements etc..

**Can someone give an explanation regarding the proper use of this shorthand syntax?**
I want to "execute" NOT "evaluate" the second statement if the first evaluates to true!

```
var succes = !data.user||(window.location = "users/profile");
```

I knew the first example was way to simple,  This one is better, it also uses comma,s to string statements after eachother, I like to know how to learn this syntax.

```
},
        hide: function (a,
        b) {
            if (f && !(500 > (new Date).getTime() - f.getTime())) {
                if (!a || "number" == typeof a) a = k();
                b || (b = $(".profile-popup"));
                j(a) && (b.fadeOut("fast"), m(!1, a));
                e && (clearInterval(e), e = null)
            }
        }
    }
}();
```

**EDIT**
I changed my first example to use the && in my code and it worked, so, that's that - for anyone else reading -, and you should use absolute url's if working with window.location

I also found another detailed explanation [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859433/an-explanation-of-shorthand-in-javascript?rq=1).

thanks, Richard

Comment: the first needs to execute window.location NOT evaluate it, so if the first one is not true it would never come to the next evaluation(in this case statement to execute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general pattern of `!obj || obj = "something"` is simply shorthand for:

```
if (obj === undefined) {
    obj = "something";
}
```

That's because `!obj` evaluates to `false` if it's undefined (the pattern also seems to *assume* that `obj` will not be defined as `true`).

Likewise, the pattern `f(a) && (g(b), h(c))` is shorthand for:

```
if (f(a) == true) {
    g(b);
    h(c);
}
```

---

For the referenced piece of code:

```
var succes = !data.user||(window.location = "users/profile");
```

What this implicitly says is:

1. If data.user is undefined, then set `success` to true.
2. Otherwise (if `data.user` *is* assigned), then *redirect* to *users/profile*.

The exact meaning is anyone's guess without knowing the context, but it appears to mean "redirect the profile screen, if user data is available, otherwise ..."

Comment: yes that's true but I had to use && instead of || I think, am not sure

Comment: @Richard `&&` doesn't make sense either, then the statement would just be unconditionally a redirect.

Comment: in the second example wich I grabbed from overflow it also uses -  j(a) && (b.fadeOut("fast"), m(!1, a)); IF the first one would be a boolean return  from a function, the second one is clearly a statement that get's executed???

Comment: @Richard `if (!a || "number" == typeof a)` "if a is undefined or a number".

Comment: @Richard `b || (b = $(".profile-popup"));` "if b is undefined then assign it to ..."

Comment: Yes, I get the evaluation types, but not the ones that EXECUTE statements, sorry those where assignments, YES I need to learn those too, thanks - also,@dbaseman, can you explain the second samplecode?

Comment: @Richard `j(a) && (b.fadeOut("fast"), m(!1, a));` -- if the first part `j(a)` is false, then the second part won't execute.  So it's like writing "if j(a) == true then execute this..."

Comment: ok, SO you really can execute statements with this,in my code it didn't work, but that's because I didn't use &&. @dbaseman, regarding proper use, can you also string statements after eachother with a comma and do you have to wrap both statements in parenthesis??- for clarification please. It helps me to read plugin code better also

Comment: thanks for updating your answer, now it is not so vague to me anymore!

Answer (score 5):

I think you're missing another `=`:

```
var succes = !data.user || (window.location == "users/profile");
```

Your example assigns, whereas `==` is a comparison.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Window.location is *never* going to be equal to that.  I think the statement is meant to be the assignment `=`, to *redirect* the user to a profile screen.

Comment: `window.location` is an object, so comparison `window.location == "users/profile"` dows not make sense.

Comment: In other words, *window.location* is the URL of the current page.  The URL always has to have at least `http://hostname` in it, so that is no different than writing `var success = !data.user || false;`, which in turn is equivalent to writing `var success = false;`

Comment: thanks, but I thought you could somehow execute statements NOT evaluate