# How can I get rid of error - TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

The while statement keeps throwing an error (TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined) however the console.log still outputs the result that it's meant to.

```
 var hold = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < (clothes.length - 1); i++) {
   let count = 0;
   if (hold.length === 0) {
     hold.push(clothes[i]);
   } else {
     console.log(clothes[i][8], hold[count][8]);
     while (clothes[i][8] < hold[count][8]) {
       count++;
     }
     hold.slice(count, 0, clothes[i]);
   }
 }
```

Comment: You're incrementing `count` beyond the length of `hold`

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit please do not edit and change `var` to `let` - that's quite often the cause of problems (unlikely in this case).  Keep the author's intent.

Comment: @freedomn-m I added a line to prevent the count from exceeding the length of hold and I am still getting the same error -  while ((clothes[i][8] < hold[count][8]) && count < hold.length){

Comment: That's why I deleted the answer, it doesn't *quite* work - working on a complete solution rather than just that part - change the order of the comparsion so the length check is first: `while (count<hold.length && clothes[i][0] < hold[count][0]) {`

Comment: Next issue you'll get is that you're using `slice` instead of `splice`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks got that but still got the error on the while statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the code increments `count` beyond the length of `hold[]`

```
while (clothes[i][8] < hold[count][8]){
  count ++;
};
```

stepping through manually:

- clothes[0] gets added as hold[0] by the "if hold is empty clause"
- clothes[1] gets compared with hold[0] and is `<` so count++
- clothes[1] gets compared with hold[1], but there's no hold[1], so you get the error

Add a clause in the `while`

```
while (count < hold.length && clothes[i][8] < hold[count][8]){
  count ++;
};
```

*Note* the length check must be first otherwise you still get the same error (there's other ways such as `break` out of the `while`).   The 2nd part of the `&&` is [only valuated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3859478/2181514) if the first part is `true`.

---

You have other issues stopping a complete solution:

```
for (let i = 0; i < (clothes.length - 1); i++){
```

will loop to the length-1, so if you have 3 elements, you only get two.  You need to use *either*

- `i<clothes.length`
- `i<=(clothese.length-1)`

and

```
hold.slice(count, 0, clothes[i]);
```

is not the syntax for `.slice` and slice returns a new array, does not change the array in place.  This should be

```
hold.splice(count, 0, clothes[i]);
```

Giving an updated snippet:

```js
var clothes = [[2],[1],[3]];

var hold = []
for (let i = 0; i < clothes.length; i++) {
  var count = 0;
  if (hold.length === 0) {
    hold.push(clothes[i]);
  } else {
    while (count<hold.length && clothes[i][0] < hold[count][0]) {
      count++;
    };
    if (count == hold.length) {
      hold.push(clothes[i])
    }
    else  {
      hold.splice(count, 0, clothes[i]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(hold.join(","));
```